# Performing compare operation on Array in java to find salary more then a base salary

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters, double

I've been stuck trying to write this code for some time. Basically, I have to start with 1 double array named salaries and 1 double parameter named max. The method should count all of the salaries greater than max.
Here is an example.

- salaries : an array of double (any length)
- max :the maximum salary

return the count of salaries greater than max

```
money({150.0, 250.0, 350.0}, 10.0) returns 3
money({150.0, 250.0, 350.0}, 100.0) returns 2
money({150.0, 250.0, 350.0}, 500.0) returns 0
```

If someone could guide me through this or show me what to do, I'd much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code is very similar to plain English:

- Declare a count variable
- For each salary, if the salary is more than the max, add 1 to the count
- Return the count

In java 7, this would be 4 lines.
In java 8, this would be 1 line.